# Scaling An Application With Many Shared Objects

Tags: c#, database, wpf, mvvm, repository

I have a C# application (C#, WPF, Caliburn.Micro MVVM, Dapper) involving a Data Layer, Business Logic and Views.

As an example, a PK value (ClientGUID) from the Client table is used in many parts of the application and other tables. There is a function to Merge 2 Clients, which replaces all instances of the removed ClientGUID with the kept ClientGUID. In the UnitOfWork class, this is done by referencing all the tables and fields that need to be updated. This works fine.

As the application expands, and more tables and fields are added where a ClientGUID FK could be stored, how do we effectively remember to update all these functions, such as Merge, to include the new Tables/Fields?

Comment: Take a look at [Software Engineering SE: How to keep a big and complex software product maintainable over the years?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129327/how-to-keep-a-big-and-complex-software-product-maintainable-over-the-years)

Comment: I appreciate that link. It's a heavy topic to address generally. I'm looking for a specific strategy to trigger or force developers to update some business logic layer when a new Table is introduced. Something more sophisticated than, "Where do we use ClientGUID in the Application?"